# GridWorld Adding flowers to random locations

Tags: java, actor, gridworld

I'm trying to make a a "GrowingFlower" that just adds flowers to random locations.  The amount of Flowers that are added is based off of a random number.  When I run the Flower after I hit act 6 times it dies like its supposed to but it never adds any flowers so I need your help solving this please.  Thank You in advance.

Here is the code for the "GrowingFlower"

```
package projects.flowers;

import info.gridworld.actor.ActorWorld;
import info.gridworld.actor.Flower;

public class GrowingFlower extends Flower {

private int Growing = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
private int age = 0;
ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();



public void act(){
    Growing = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
    age++;
    if (age == 1){
        switch(Growing){
        case 0:
            removeSelfFromGrid();
        case 1:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 2:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 3:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 4:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        }
    }
    else if (age == 2){
        switch(Growing){
        case 0:
            removeSelfFromGrid();
        case 1:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 2:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 3:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 4:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        }
    } else if(age == 3)  {
        switch(Growing) {
        case 0:
            removeSelfFromGrid();
        case 1:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 2:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 3:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 4:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());

        }
    } else if (age == 4){
        switch(Growing) {

        case 0:
            removeSelfFromGrid();
        case 1:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 2:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 3:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 4:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());

        }

    } else if (age == 5){
        switch(Growing) {

        case 0:
            removeSelfFromGrid();
        case 1:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());

        case 2:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 3:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        case 4:
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());
            world.add(new GrowingFlower());

        }

    } else if (age == 6){
        removeSelfFromGrid();
    }



}

}
```

And Here is my runner

```
package projects.firstProject;



import projects.flowers.GrowingFlower;
import info.gridworld.actor.ActorWorld;

public class FlowerRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();
    world.add(new GrowingFlower());
    world.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, you could really do with factoring out those copy-pasted `switch` statements and that big `if-else` chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so familiar with this "GridWorld" framework, so this **might** not be an acceptable answer, but too long for a comment, and ... may be helpful nevertheless:

I **think** that the problem is that you are creating a new world in your `GrowingFlower` instances:

```
public class GrowingFlower extends Flower {
    ...
    ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();
```

Later, in the `act` method, you are adding new `GrowingFlower` instances to this world, but **not** to the world that you created (and showed!) in the `main` method.

So the solution *might* be to change the code as follows:

**1.** Change the constructor of your `GrowingFlower` class to accept the "world" where the new flowers should be added:

```
public class GrowingFlower extends Flower {

    private int Growing = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
    private int age = 0;

    ActorWorld world; // Don't create a new world here!

    // Instead, use the world that is passed in 
    // in the constructor:
    GrowingFlower(ActorWorld world)
    {
        this.world = world;
    }

    ...
```

**2.** Pass in the world from the main method to your first `GrowingFlower`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();
    world.add(new GrowingFlower(world)); // Pass it in here!
    world.show();
}
```

---

Apart from that, you should refactor your `act` method a bit:

```
public void act(){
    Growing = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
    age++;
    if (age < 6){
        handleGrowing();
    }
    else {
        removeSelfFromGrid();
    }
}

private void handleGrowing()
{
    switch(Growing){
    case 0:
        removeSelfFromGrid();
    case 1:
        world.add(new GrowingFlower());
    case 2:
        world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        world.add(new GrowingFlower());
    case 3:
        world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        world.add(new GrowingFlower());
    case 4:
        world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        world.add(new GrowingFlower());
        world.add(new GrowingFlower());
    }
}
```

(As far as I see, this should still have the same behavior)

Comment: +1 for an answer that would work whether this were a GridWorld problem or not. (btw, GridWorld is the AP CS "case study" to help teach programming)

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you so much.  First time using stack over flow and it was a great experience thank you again!